# Javascript not working if i use it externally

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Tutorial</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="alert" id="alert">
        <p>Alert Alert Alert Alert Alert</p>
        <button onclick="close()"><p>&times;</p></button>
    </div>
<script src="script.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my script.js:

```
function close() {
    document.getElementById("alert").style.display = "none";
}
```

for some reason i can't use it externally, but when i use it inline it works. i've been searching for the answer for hours, but i can't find it anywhere, please help!

Comment: Don't call your function `close()`, it conflicts with `window.close()`

Comment: @Barmar does it explain why the question's code doesn't work?

Comment: Probably. When you try to call `close()` in the `onclick`, it's calling `window.close()`, not your function.

Comment: Remember, top-level variables are part of the `window` object.

Comment: Thank you so much, you are a hero. I cant believe i just did a dumb thing like that, im embarassed lmao

Comment: yeah. can confirm on JS fiddle. changing the function name to anything but close works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the name of the function from 'close' to another name like 'hideAlert'

```js
function hideAlert() {
    document.getElementById("alert").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div class="alert" id="alert">
            <p>Alert Alert Alert Alert Alert</p>
            <button onclick="hideAlert()"><p>&times;</p></button>
        </div>
```